# When i enable npm Two-Factor Authentication, something unexpected occurred

Tags: npm

Something unexpected occurred with diagnostics id: 734bedf92bb700cb_1f7a.

The authenticator and appsix-digit code all right, bug got error with 503 , then click submit button got 500.

why is it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8JPY.png)